# Setting width and height of svg in Polymer element

Tags: svg, polymer

This is probably just some stupid mistake I'm making, but I'm not able to identify the cause of the problem. I'm creating a Polymer element containing a SVG element. I have tried several ways to set the width and height of the svg element, but all my efforts seem to be stripped away from the resulting page. I inspected the result in the latest version of both Chrome and Firefox, but in each of them none of the width or height attributes are left and the CSS properties seem to have disappeared. The svg is in both cases 300 pixels wide and 150 pixels high.

This is `svg-test.html`:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="svg-test">

  <style>
    svg {
      width: {{width}};
      height: {{height}};
    }
  </style>

  <template>
    <svg width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}"></svg>
  </template>

</dom-module>

<script>

  Polymer({

    is: 'svg-test',

    properties: {
      width: {
        type: Number,
        value: 200
      },
      height: {
        type: Number,
        value: 200
      }
    }

  });

</script>
```

This is a test page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <script src="../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="svg-test.html">

</head>
<body>

  <svg-test></svg-test>
  <svg-test width="300" height="15"></svg-test>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is `bower.json`:

```
{
  "name": "svg-test",
  "main": "svg-test.html",
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use the properties in your css declaration. This is invalid and won't work. (**edit**: having done a quick google search, this seems to have been possible at one point and my have been removed for now. Hopefully someone else may be able to clear this up). Secondly, to bind to an attribute, you need to use the `$=` syntax

See [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#native-binding)

> There are a handful of extremely common native element attributes which can also be modified as properties. Due to cross-browser limitations with the ability to place binding braces {{...}} in some of these attribute values, as well as the fact that some of these attributes map to differently named JavaScript properties, it is recommended to always use attribute binding (using $=) when binding dynamic values to these specific attributes, rather than binding to their property names.

So your element should look like (note the `$=` on the `width` and `height` attributes:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="svg-test">
  <style>
    // no style
  </style>
  <template>
    <svg width$="{{width}}" height$="{{height}}"></svg>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'svg-test',
    properties: {
      width: {
        type: Number,
        value: 200
      },
      height: {
        type: Number,
        value: 200
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It appears I was mainly looking at 0.5 Polymer examples and I hadn't got round to data-binding. Thanks. This works now.